# Why preg_match fails to get the result?

Tags: php

I have the below text displayed on the browser and trying to get the URL from the string.

string 1 = voice-to-text from #switzerland: http://bit.ly/lnpDC12D

When I try to use preg_match and trying to get the URL, but it fails

```
$urlstr = "";
preg_match('/\b((?#protocol)https?|ftp):\/\/((?#domain)[-A-Z0-9.]+)((?#file)\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?((?#parameters)\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%

=~_|!:,.;]*)?/i', $urlstr, $match);

echo $match[0];
```

I think #switzerland: has one more http// ... will it be problem ?

the above split works perfect for the below string,

voice-to-text: http://bit.ly/jDcXrZg

Comment: in Other words, Can I take only bit.ly urls from the string? for example, string 1 = voice-to-text from #switzerland: http://bit.ly/lnpDC12D  ... I need only "http://bit.ly/lnpDC12D"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your request, here is a way to do it :

```
$str = 'voice-to-text from <a href="search.twitter.com/…;: http://bit.ly/lnpDC12D';
preg_match("~(bit.ly/\S+)~", $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => bit.ly/lnpDC12D
    [1] => bit.ly/lnpDC12D
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will be better choice than regex based code. Something like this may work (*assuming your URL always starts with http*):

```
$str = "voice-to-text from #switzerland: http://bit.ly/lnpDC12D";
$pos = strrpos($str, "http://");
if ($pos>=0) {
   var_dump(parse_url(substr($str, $pos)));
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(6) "bit.ly"
  ["path"]=>
  string(9) "/lnpDC12D"
}
```

Comment: It fails the real string which I get , voice-to-text from <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23switzerland">#switzerland</a>: http://bit.ly/lcXnpC9D

Comment: As I said earlier, "#switzerland: ".. it has one more http like <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23switzerland">#switzerland</a> , so it reads always this link instead of bit.ly  ...

Comment: I edited my answer to search for last occurrence of `http://` in your string, please try it now.